# Tor on Fedora 32, unable to run

Tags: fedora

Running the following below, but unable to run the below tor

fedora 32
tor-browser-linux64-10.0.1_en-US.tar.xz

Have verify PGP signatures & extracted tar, checked for file execution.

drwx------.  9 fischer fischer 4.0K Jan  1  2000 Browser

-rwx------.  1 fischer fischer 1.8K Oct 20 18:21 start-tor-browser.desktop

-rw-rw-r--.  1 fischer fischer  801 Oct 18 13:55 tor-browser-linux64-10.0.1_en-US.tar.xz.asc

-rw-rw-r--.  1 fischer fischer 5.0K Oct 18 13:44 tor.keyring

But still unable to start.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How far does it get? Does a window appear? Is there an error message? Is there any output if you start it from the command line?

Comment: Run from the cli with the following output : Launching './Browser/start-tor-browser --detach'...

From GUI is nothing....Is there an output redirection or log which I can check or run?